# I can't access an html element inside <asp:multiview>

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I access an html element inside an `<asp:multiview>` using jquery or javascript?

Let's say I have the structure for multiview:

```
<div runat="server" class="tabContents" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <asp:MultiView id="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" Runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="v1" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f1" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>        
        <asp:View ID="v2" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f2" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v3" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f3" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v4" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f4" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v5" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f5" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v6" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f6" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>        
        <asp:View ID="v7" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f7" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v8" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f8" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v9" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f9" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="v10" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="f10" runat="server" style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</div>
```

I tried this code in the code behind:

```
 string s;
        s =
            "<script>" +
            "$('#f" + index++ + "').src(" + "'" + url + "'" + ");" + 
            "</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ExeCuteScript", s);
```

but it's not working.

Please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: You need to wrap the code in onload event i.e. `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `multiviews` before but if `f1` is accessible from your code behind then your `jquery` can be as simple as:

```
$('#<%= f1.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: Ok let me try this. However since f1 is accessible in the code behind can i change the "src" directly from there?

Comment: yeap, as long as a control has a `runat="server"` tag, you can use the `Attributes` collection like this: `f1.Attributes["src"] = "http://blah.com";`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the rendered markup of the page, you'll see that the IDs of the elements you're trying to access aren't the same as the ones you assigned. This is because ASP.NET generates unique IDs for `runat="server"` elements.

However, you will notice that the very end of the ID is the actual ID you specified in your XAML. You could do this by using the jQuery "endswith" selector like so:

```
String.Format("$('[id$=f{0}]').src('{1}');", index++, url);
```

So your code block becomes:

```
string s;
s = "<script>" +
    String.Format("$('[id$=f{0}]').src('{1}');", index++, url) + 
    "</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ExeCuteScript", s);
```

Alternatively, if you are not using your iframes in your codebehind, just remove `runat="server"` from them.

Comment: I did this string s;
            s =
                "<script>" +
                "String.Format(\"$('[id$=f{0}]').src('{1}');\"," + idx + "," + url + ");" +
                "</script>";

Comment: You don't need the escaping in String.Format - it is a C# method. You want to execute it, not write it out. `"<script>" + String.Format("$('[id$=f{0}]').src('{1}')", idx, url) + "</script>";`

Comment: Oh I see. Ok let me try it now. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I tried it and this is the whole event: protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
            int idx = index + 1;
            string s;
            s = "<script>" + String.Format("$('[id$=f{0}]').src('{1}')", idx, url) + "</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", s);
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = index;
        }

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What is the rendered markup? My answer is correct within the parameters of your question, so if it doesn't work, you've done something else wrong.

Comment: Can we continue this through chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31236/discussion-between-chris-n-p-and-ant-p)